# powershell missing leading 0 in excel

Tags: excel, csv, powershell

I've spent two days troubleshooting why a 4 digit number is being passed through my 5 digit regex. When you open the CSV in Excel it shows 4 digits '1234' when you open it in notepad, you'll see '01234'. Is there a way to do export-csv in powershell that will maintain the proper format? I know the format is related to how Excel thinks it should look like. I'm hoping to find a solution in powershell where you force the number format.

Is it possible that if the first digit is 0 that you can prepend with special character that will make the first 0 visible in excel?

Comment: You can escape the number formatting in Excel by prepending the cell value with an apostrophe: `'01234` will show up as `01234` in Excel

Comment: Hi Mathias, that did help, but....now I'm also seeing the single quote in the cell, like: '01234. Is there a better way of doing this or accept that there will be a ' in the cell?

Comment: The best way of doing it would be to apply formatting *in Excel* - a CSV doesn't have a formatting layer, stop trying to force one onto it :) [Use excel instead if it's that important](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/01/10/powershell-and-excel-fast-safe-and-reliable/)

Comment: That's what I'm concluding. I was hoping to automate the process without having to go back and formatting. What I'll probably do is write to Excel, it just requires more coding than just simply export-csv. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

(In case this remains unsolved or can help someone else with this issue)

Excel's [WorkBook.OpenText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx) is helpful here. You can specify the [Column Data Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193030.aspx).

```
$xlSession = New-Object -ComObject excel.application

$file = Get-Item "C:\MyDir\MyFile.csv

$xlsession.WorkBooks.OpenText(`
                    $file.FullName,    # Filename
                    2,            # Origin
                    1,            # StartRow
                    1,            # DataType
                    1,            # TextQualifier
                    $false,       # ConsecutiveDelimiter
                    $false,       # Tab
                    $false,       # Semicolon
                    $true,        # Comma
                    $false,       # Space
                    $false,       # Other
                    $false,       # OtherChar


                    # FieldInfo; the important part.
                    # I am telling Excel that columns 1, 2 and 3 are type 2 (Text)
                    # More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193030.aspx

                    @(@(1,2),@(2,2),@(3,2))         

)

$workBook = $xlsession.ActiveWorkbook

$workBook.SaveAs("C:\MyDir\Somefile.xlsx")
```